# GoogleAccountCredential getSelectedAccountName() is returning null after setting it and implementing permissions

Tags: java, android, gmail-api

I'm using the GET_ACCOUNTS permission from the CONTACTS group and also handling it in my code. I just can't figure out why the account name is still null after setting it. The app already has permission since no dialog box pops up to tell the user to grant the permission.

I set the credential in the onCreate like so:

```
        mCredential = GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(
                getApplicationContext(), Arrays.asList(SCOPES))
                .setBackOff(new ExponentialBackOff());
```

Here's where I'm attempting to set the name:

```
/**
 * Attempts to set the account used with the API credentials. If an account
 * name was previously saved it will use that one; otherwise an account
 * picker dialog will be shown to the user. Note that the setting the
 * account to use with the credentials object requires the app to have the
 * GET_ACCOUNTS permission, which is requested here if it is not already
 * present. The AfterPermissionGranted annotation indicates that this
 * function will be rerun automatically whenever the GET_ACCOUNTS permission
 * is granted.
 */
@AfterPermissionGranted(REQUEST_PERMISSION_GET_ACCOUNTS)
    private void chooseAccount() {
        if (EasyPermissions.hasPermissions(
                this, Manifest.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS)) {

            String accountName = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
                    .getString(PREF_ACCOUNT_NAME, null);
            if (accountName != null) {
                mCredential.setSelectedAccountName(accountName); // I set the account name here

                Log.d("MESSAGE", accountName); // this prints out the account name as an email
                Log.d("MESSAGE", mCredential.getSelectedAccountName()); // this throws a null pointer

                getResultsFromApi();
            } else {
                // Start a dialog from which the user can choose an account
                Log.d("MESSAGE", "Start dialogue box to select account");
                startActivityForResult(
                        mCredential.newChooseAccountIntent(),
                        REQUEST_ACCOUNT_PICKER);
            }
        } else {
            // Request the GET_ACCOUNTS permission via a user dialog
            Log.d("MESSAGE", "Creates dialogue box to request permission");
            EasyPermissions.requestPermissions(
                    this,
                    "This app needs to access your Google account (via Contacts).",
                    REQUEST_PERMISSION_GET_ACCOUNTS,
                    Manifest.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS);
        }
    }
```

Here are my permissions from the Manifest file:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
```

This is my very first project and I'm not very experienced. Any help will be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: You are using Preferences to get account name but you have not saved it anywhere it seems. Have you saved it in preferences though?

Comment: Yeah it's saved in a Preference created in a method that's called when the app is launched for the very first time. It saves the account name in that preference after requesting it from the user. The above method access that already existing Preference. The account name is saved in the string. It just won't let me set it to the credential.

Comment: what's the value of accountName before you passed it in  mCredential.setSelectedAccountName(accountName); ?

Comment: @noogui it's the email I'm testing it with.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. User setSelectedAccount() instead of setSelectedAccountName().

```
 mCredential = GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(
                getApplicationContext(), Arrays.asList(SCOPES))
                .setBackOff(new ExponentialBackOff());

        // to set accountName manually instead of prompting user to select it
        mCredential.setSelectedAccount(new Account("xyz@gmail.com", "come.android.example"));
```

Give the gmail account as the first parameter and your package name as the second. It should work.